# Compute density of states in momentum space and in phase space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

In the book *Cosmology* by Daniel Baumann, I encountered the following claim:

> Solving the Schrödinger equation with periodic boundary condicions gives: $$\vec{p}=\dfrac{h}{L}(r_1\hat{x}+r_2\hat{y}+r_3\hat{z})$$ where $r_i=0,\pm 1,\pm 2...$ and $h$ is Planck's constant. The density of states in momentum space $\{\vec{p}\}$ is then $L^3/h^3=V/h^3$, and the state density in phase space $\{x,\vec{p}\}$ is $1/h^3$. If the particle has $g$ internal degrees of freedom, then the density of states becomes $g/h^3$.

As someone with very little background on statistical mechanics, I'm having trouble understanding how these calculations are made. Can anyone help me, or at least point me in the right direction to attempt the calculation myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about momentum space, the 3d space of all possible momentum vectors $\mathbf{p}$. Your equation

$$\mathbf{p} = \frac{h}{L} \left( r_1 \hat{\mathbf{x}} + r_2 \hat{\mathbf{y}} + r_3 \hat{\mathbf{z}} \right), \quad r_i \in \mathbb{Z}$$

tells us that the momentum of the system of interest can't take on any arbitrary value in momentum space. Rather, $\mathbf{p}$ is restricted to those values such that each component of $\mathbf{p}$ is an integer multiple of $h/L$. If we look at momentum space, and we draw a dot at the tip of each of these allowed $\mathbf{p}$ vectors, then we get a grid of dots that looks something like

[image]

where adjacent dots are separated by a distance $h/L$ in every direction. A single 2d slice of this grid looks like this:

[image]

Now, the "density of states" in *momentum space* just refers to the number of such allowed states per unit "volume" of momentum space - in other words, the number of grid points per unit volume. Since adjacent points are separated by $h/L$, there are $L/h$ points per unit length along any direction, and therefore the density is just $(L/h) (L/h) (L/h) = L^3/h^3$. So, if the system is contained within a cubic box of side length $L$ with volume $V = L^3$, then the momentum space density of states is $V/h^3$.

What about the density of states in *phase space*, the 6d joint space of positions and momenta? Well, the system has a volume $V$ available to it, but there is only a single state associated with this volume for each allowed choice of $\mathbf{p}$. Therefore the phase space density of states is $(V/h^3)(1/V) = 1/h^3$.

Finally, we've assumed so far that for each choice of $\mathbf{p}$, there is only a single associated state of the system. In other words, specifying $\mathbf{p}$ fully specifies the state of the system. However, suppose instead that there are $g$ states for each choice of $\mathbf{p}$, due to additional internal degrees of freedom. Then the phase space density of states is instead $g/h^3$.